# kafka message key as key field/column in HDFS

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, debezium

So I use the debezium `key.field.name` in my MySQL source connector to add a field into my topic.

The message looks below after landing on topic.

```
{"id":20,"__PKtableowner":"reviewDB.review.search_user_02"}:{"before":null,"after":{"search_user_all_shards.Value":{"id":20,"name":{"string":"oliver"},"email":{"string":"bob@abc.com"},"department":{"string":"sales"},"modified":"2021-01-06T09:27:02Z"}},"source":{"version":"1.0.2.Final","connector":"mysql","name":"reviewDB","ts_ms":1609925222000,"snapshot":{"string":"false"},"db":"review","table":{"string":"search_user_02"},"server_id":1,"gtid":null,"file":"binlog.000002","pos":14630,"row":0,"thread":{"long":13},"query":null},"op":"c","ts_ms":{"long":1609925222956}}
```

Where in,
key is

```
{"id":20,"__PKtableowner":"reviewDB.review.search_user_02"}
```

and value is

```
{"before":null,"after":{"search_user_all_shards.Value":{"id":20,"name":{"string":"oliver"},"email":{"string":"bob@abc.com"},"department":{"string":"sales"},"modified":"2021-01-06T09:27:02Z"}},"source":{"version":"1.0.2.Final","connector":"mysql","name":"reviewDB","ts_ms":1609925222000,"snapshot":{"string":"false"},"db":"review","table":{"string":"search_user_02"},"server_id":1,"gtid":null,"file":"binlog.000002","pos":14630,"row":0,"thread":{"long":13},"query":null},"op":"c","ts_ms":{"long":1609925222956}}
```

As part of my sink hdfsSinkConnector I need to fetch the message key `"__PKtableowner":"reviewDB.review.search_user_02`
as part of a column or field in hdfs or hive.

The only SMT I found is ValueToKey, but it seems it didn't fit my use case because it's fetching from the value and not from the message key. I've tried (InsertField, CreateKey, ExtractField, etc.) Almost all of the transformation you can find here but no luck.
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/valuetokey.html

I'm looking for a KeyToValue kind of SMT or if there are other workaround.

Below are my source and sink configurations.
Source:

```
{
  "name": "REVIEW__MYSQL__search_user__source",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "review.search_user_logs",
    "database.history.consumer.max.block.ms": "3000",
    "include.schema.changes": "false",
    "database.history.consumer.session.timeout.ms": "30000",
    "database.history.kafka.consumer.group": "compose-connect-group",
    "snapshot.new.tables": "parallel",
    "database.history.kafka.sasl.mechanism": "GSSAPI",
    "database.whitelist": "review",
    "database.history.producer.sasl.mechanism": "GSSAPI",
    "database.user": "root",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "time.precision.mode": "connect",
    "database.server.name": "reviewDB",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.history.consumer.heartbeat.interval.ms": "1000",
    "min.row.count.to.stream.results": "0",
    "database.hostname": "mysql",
    "database.password": "example",
    "database.history.consumer.sasl.mechanism": "GSSAPI",
    "snapshot.mode": "when_needed",
    "table.whitelist": "review.search_user_(.*)",
    "transforms": "Reroute",
    "transforms.Reroute.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
    "transforms.Reroute.topic.regex": "reviewDB.review.search_user_(.*)",
    "transforms.Reroute.topic.replacement": "search_user_all_shards",
    "transforms.Reroute.key.field.name": "__PKtableowner"
  }
}
```

Sink

```
{ "name": "REVIEW__MYSQL__search_user__sink",
  "config":
  {
      "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
      "topics.dir": "/_incr_files",
      "flush.size": 1,
      "tasks.max": 1,
      "timezone": "UTC",
      "rotate.interval.ms": 5000,
      "locale": "en",
      "hadoop.home": "/etc/hadoop",
      "logs.dir": "/_incr_files_wal",
      "hive.integration": "false",
      "partition.duration.ms": "20000",
      "hadoop.conf.dir": "/etc/hadoop",
      "topics": "search_user_all_shards",
      "hdfs.url": "hdfs://namenode:9000",
      "transforms": "unwrap,insertTopicOffset,insertTimeStamp",
      "transforms.insertTimeStamp.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
      "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "true",
      "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
      "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "rewrite",
      "transforms.insertTimeStamp.timestamp.field": "spdb_landing_timestamp",
      "transforms.insertTopicOffset.offset.field": "spdb_topic_offset",
      "transforms.insertTopicOffset.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
      "schema.compatibility": "NONE",
      "path.format": "'partition'=YYYY-MM-dd-HH",
      "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your key is a Struct, the best way I'm aware of is this SMT that effectively wraps the key and value into a new, nested value

https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-archive

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating my own. :)

https://github.com/Verdado/kafka-connect-custom-transforms